# Undefined Index while uploading file in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

[image]

Problem occurs in these two lines:

```
$product_image =  $_FILES['product_image']['name'][0];

$product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'][0];
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php

   if(isset($_POST['insert_post'])){

      $product_title = $_POST['product_title'];
      $product_cat = $_POST['product_cat'];
      $product_brand = $_POST['product_title'];
      $product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
      $product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];
      $product_keywords = $_POST['product_keywords'];

      $product_image =  $_FILES['product_image']['name'][0];
      $product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'][0];

      move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp,"product_images/$product_image");

       echo $insert_product = "insert into products
     (product_cat,product_brand,product_title,product_price,product_desc,product_image,product_keywords)
     values('$product_cat','$product_brand','$product_title','$product_price','$product_desc','$product_image','$product_keywords')";


     $insert_pro = mysqli_query($con,$insert_product);

     if($insert_pro){
         echo "<script>alert('Product Has Been Inserted')</script>";
         echo "<script>window.open('insert_product.php','_self')</script>";

     }

    }
?>
```

Comment: which index is undefined ?

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions that lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem.* Please edit your post accordingly to add sufficient detail so that people may help you.

Comment: // $product_image = $_FILES['product_image']['name'][0]; // $product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'][0]; problem occurs in these 2 lines

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you have add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `form` element
2. and make sure your file type input is named `product_image`

Comment: can i get your mail. then i will send whole website, here em geting problem with text indentation bro...

Answer (score 0):

```
$product_image =  $_FILES['product_image']['name'];

$product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];
```

Try it